# How to know which code area the intent is coming from in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that listens to certain Action. I have 2 places that send this action. Is there a way to distinguish which place it is coming from? Can I set something similar to Request Code somewhere?

Thank you

EDIT: Mayeb  I shouldve clarified more. My problem is that I listen to this action 
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
Which gets sent by the camera app when a picture is taken.
However, inside my app, I also allow the user to take a picture by using the default camera app so this action is also being sent.
My question is how do I differentiate between the action sent "when a user open the default camera app and takes a picture outside my app" AND "when the user uses my app and take a picture". Both will send same action to the broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

```
public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String broadcastMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("senderNum");

            Log.i("broadcastReceiver", "broadcastReceiver=" + broadcastMessage
                    + "-------" + verificationCode);


        }
    };

public void onResume() {
        messageFilter = new IntentFilter();
        messageFilter.addAction("RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION_NEW");
        viewRegistration.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, messageFilter);
    }

    public void onPause() {

        viewRegistration.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    }
```

in gcm service put this action in intent:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(final Context ctx, Intent intent) {


            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.setAction("RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION_NEW");
                intent2.putExtra("senderNum", senderNum);
                intent2.putExtra("verificationCode",
                        ReturnValidationcode(message));
                context.sendBroadcast(intent2);

    }
```

based on RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION_NEW ,you can get broadcast message intent.

Comment: Thank you bt does not answer my question. Please check the EDIT